# Understanding bitwise XOR (^) with boolean variables

Tags: c++, boolean, bitwise-operators, boolean-operations, bitwise-xor

I'm from a game programming background and I've just come across a bitwise XOR ^. I've seen examples of how it works with integers, but I'm a bit confused about the result with boolean values. I know a bool is either 0 or 1, but after testing I haven't been able to replicate the ^ result with simple operators. Could someone please explain to me what the following code snippet (specifically the ^) is doing? Many thanks.

```
bool body1awake = rigidbody1.isAwake;
bool body2awake = rigidbody2.isAwake;
if (body1awake ^ body2awake)
{
    if (body1awake) rigidbody2.SetAwake();
    else rigidbody1.SetAwake();
}
```

Comment: Search the internet for "Exclusive Or truth table".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `bool` is a narrower type than an `int`, both arguments are implicitly converted to an `int` prior to the XOR being evaluated. `true` assumes the value `1`, and `false` assumes the value `0`.

If that result is non-zero then the `if` body runs, and that happens if and only if `body1awake` is not equal to `body2awake`.

So perhaps the equivalent

```
if (body1awake != body2awake)
```

would have been better. If the author thinks their way is faster then they need a stern talking to with compiler optimisations and *as-if* rule being introduced into the conversation.

Comment: Thanks, I really am just overthinking it then.

Comment: Even *without* compiler optimisation and as-if rule there’s no reason whatsoever to assume that `^` should be faster than `!=` on booleans. Both map directly to assembly instructions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph it depends if bool actually reprented by same storage as int, or implocit conversion may have a cost

Answer (score 3):

Exclusive or of two bits is true when only one of them is set.  If both are set or not set then it is false.  Since `bool` basically represents a single bit (0 or 1 are its only values)

```
if (body1awake ^ body2awake)
```

means that the condition will be true on when `body1awake != body2awake`.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I am overthinking it!

Comment: @EllieDunstan: Na, the programmer was overthinking it. `if ((body1awake 
 + body2awake) % 2)` is another way of writing this.

Comment: @Bathsheba You forgot `… != false`.

Comment: @EllieDunstan Don't worry about it.  The person that wrote it should have left a comment, or used `if (body1awake != body2awake)`

Comment: The person wot wrote it should buy lunch for the whole dev team.

Comment: "Monseniour is a connoseur of perversions". But it works and is legal